# How to save an image from a link to Firebase storage with firebase web?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

In my iOS App I want to display an image of a webcam: https://www.alpenblickzeneggen.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/webcamBild.jpg.

But with iOS 10 and AppTransportSecurity and all those problems I think it's better to do it otherwise:

- Get the image from the link with Firebase for the web
- Save that image to Firebase storage
- Download the image in my iOS App from Firebase storage

But, how can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the site is using reasonably modern ciphers, ATS isn't going to be a problem here...

If you're already storing your image somewhere else, just use something like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to download and display your image:

```
@import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://www.alpenblickzeneggen.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/webcamBild.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

If the image is changing, and you need a place to store that data, Firebase Storage is a good choice.